# How to pick up a random key from a table in Lua?

Tags: random, lua, love2d

I'm using this code to draw a random pics from this table

```
FishImages = {image1 = love.graphics.newImage("bg/fish1.png"),
            image2 = love.graphics.newImage("bg/fish2.png"),
            image3 = love.graphics.newImage("bg/fish3.png"),
            image4 = love.graphics.newImage("bg/fish4.png"),}
```

with this function `love.graphics.draw({FishImages.image1#--I guess the modification is here },pos.x,pos.y)`

so how to pick up a random key from a table in Lua ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`math.random(1,4)`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.random) generates a random integer in the range `1` to `4`. So you can use:

```
FishImages['image' .. tostring(math.random(1,4))]
```

Comment: thanks , its working but not like the way i need, love2d calling the love.graphics.draw every moving pixel  so i get the 4 images moving at the same time